# WSS - Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

Tags: node.js, https, certificate, ssl-certificate

**Please do not mark as duplicate** since all of the other questions on SO are not quite like this one, and all solutions have been attempted and are irrelevant.

---

I am working on **Windows** trying to create a BinaryServer with node.js and allow clients to connect to it over HTTPS, for audio streaming purposes.

**Node JS code**:

```
var binaryServer = require('binaryjs').BinaryServer;
var https = require('https');
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('../cert/example.com.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('../cert/example.com.crt')
};
var httpsserver = https.createServer(options).listen(9001);
var server = binaryServer({ server: httpsserver, port: 9001 });

server.on('connection', function(client) {
   .... // stuff
}
```

**Client site JS code**:

```
client = new BinaryClient('https://example.com:9001');
```

When browsing with Chrome to my site at `https://example.com/page.aspx` I get the following console message:

> Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

I am suspecting it has something to do with the certificate and the key.

The **example.com.key** is a .key file that I created using **OpenSSL**. From that key, I created a .CSR file, which I uploaded to GoDaddy, and got the  **example.com.crt** file.

What am I doing wrong?

I am struggling with this for 2 weeks, any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved - by setting different ports to the `httpsserver` and the `server` binary server.